Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after installing "Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule"
I made a web forms application with asp.net framework version 4.8. I downloaded
Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule version 2.0.0 from nuget in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule
in visual studio.
After running this application then I encounter with below error page in browser:

How can I solve it.

You need to remove that package. You are running .net framework, and that package is for .net core, and thus of course it will not work.  ONLY choose .net framework packages, and NEVER choose .net 2.x-8.x packages when running a .net framework system.

But it is released in .NET Framework 4.6.2. You can read it in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule#readme-body-tab
